# A $ G $-invariant product structure on the boundary of $ F \times \mathbb{S}^{1} $.

Tags: geometry, algebraic-topology, geometric-topology

In Meeks and Scott’s paper, *Finite Group Actions on 3-Manifolds*, they assert that if a finite group $ G $ acts on $ F \times \mathbb{S}^{1} $ (where $ F $ is a surface with boundary) while preserving the Seifert fibration up to homotopy, then the product structure on the boundary of $ F \times \mathbb{S}^{1} $ can be homotoped to be $ G $-invariant. They claim that this follows from the fact that $ G $ preserves a flat metric on the boundary.

I understand fully why it preserves a flat metric on the boundary (from lifting the flat metric on the quotient boundary), but I don’t see exactly how to show that this implies their claim.

The reference for this claim is below Theorem 2.3 on Page 299.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think if the group action preserve a flat metric on the boundary, the action is by isometries, so it maps geodesics to geodesics. The Seifert fibers on the boundary determine a single homotopy class (think of it as a topological direction) and there are simple closed geodesics in that homotopy class. In fact there is a whole foliation of the boundary surface into simple closed geodesics, each freely homotopic to any of the original Seifert fibers. This foliation is invariant with respect to the group action. Now you isotope the Seifert fibration of the manifold in a small "tubular" neighborhood of the boundary surface, while outside that neighborhood it is identity. And you do it so that the original fibers on the boundary are isotoped to be the geodesic foliation on the soudary surface.

Does that make sense?

Comment: That does make sense, what you are saying if I am correct is that you can pick meridians and longitudes for each boundary torus and then the action will send meridians to meridians and longitudes to longitudes. What I am struggling to understand is how this can be further shown to be homotoped to preserve the product structure on the boundary which is (S^1u...uS^1)xS^1. Unless I am incorrect it needs to be more than just a product map between boundary tori, it needs to be a product on the whole boundary, that is we need to pick meridians for each boundary toro that all get moved the same ...

Comment: ...distance longitudinally under the action. If you have any more thoughts I would greatly appreciate it! Thanks!

Comment: Are these smooth manifolds?

Comment: Yes, these are smooth manifolds.